# Paradox problem: "Tried contacting Github, but I can't understand the result."

Tags: package

For some time now (a month or so, I reckon), I get a strange error message after running the `paradox-upgrade-packages` command:

```
Contacting host: raw.githubusercontent.com:443
Importing package-keyring.gpg...done
Contacting host: melpa.org:80 [2 times]
Contacting host: marmalade-repo.org:80 [2 times]
gnutls.c: [0] (Emacs) fatal error: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
Contacting host: orgmode.org:80
Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:80 [2 times]
paradox--github-parse-response-code: Tried contacting Github, but I can't understand the result.  See *Paradox Github* buffer for the full result
```

My `paradox` config is this one:

```
;; ------------------ paradox -----------------------
(use-package paradox
  :ensure t
  :bind (("C-x C-u" . paradox-upgrade-packages))
  :config
  (setq paradox-execute-asynchronously t
    paradox-github-token "[private]"
    paradox-automatically-star t
    )
  :commands
  (paradox-upgrade-packages paradox-list-packages)
)
```

This is exactly the same config I have in my Macbook Pro machine, with no problems at all. However, in my Xubuntu 15.10 machine (with GNU Emacs 24.5.1) I get the said error message.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you "See *Paradox Github* buffer for the full result"?

Comment: No such buffer is created, I'm afraid.

Comment: An the *Paradox Report* buffer is created by empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to fix this. It appears to have been an SSH-key problem. I followed the instructions found [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) to generate a new SSH key  for use with GitHub, and the problem disappeared.

Comment: Could you please accept your own answer so we can mark this question as answered?